# Copy elision seems to occur even if compiling with -fno-elide-constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, copy-elision

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A& a) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl; }
    A& operator=(const A& a) { std::cout << "Copy = operator" << std::endl; }
    A(A&& a) { std::cout << "Move Constructor" << std::endl; }
    A& operator=(A&& a) { std::cout << "Move = operator" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

void f(A&& a) { std::cout << "function" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    f(A());
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the following program is:

```
Constructor
function
Destructor
```

Why is the move-constructor not called here? It seems like copy elision occurs even if I compile with the flag -fno-elide-constructors: `g++ test.cpp -fno-elide-constructors -std=c++11`

Comment: Am I being spectacularly dumb? Surely `A()` invokes the default constructor, then the anonymous temporary can bind to `f(A&&)`. What am I missing? A move constructor can only be called when you have a constructed object.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't think you are missing anything.  Given `A foo();`, then `A a{foo()};` would invoke the move constructor, but as it is, there is nothing to move to.

Comment: @Bathsheba "What am I missing?" I don't know... Some good quality personal time? Perhaps some sleep too? (don't mind me, just clowning around. Friendly kidding, no malice in it).

Comment: This isn't the issue, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **You are not move-constructing anything**.

You are just creating a temporary `A`object and then passing a reference to it. If you want to see move construction, you could e.g. change the signature of `f` to

```
void f(A a)
```